# How do I use python 3 on terminal Mac

Tags: python, macos, terminal

When I run python someCode.py in my terminal, I am actually using python 2.7

I have installed python 3.6 on my Mac and would like to use it in terminal. how can I do that?

Comment: Use `python3` while initiating command line.

Comment: You should be able to just use `python3.6 script.py`.

Comment: If you installed it with **homebrew**, either use `/usr/local/bin/python3` or change your PATH with `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` and then you can just use `python3`. Be sure to use `/usr/local/bin/pip3` to install packages for that Python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just type `python3` where you would have typed `python`.

For example open repl type `python3` run app.py program with python3.6 type `python3 app.py`

Answer (score 1):

type `python3` on command window/ terminal window & press enter,
for exit from python type `quit()` & press enter